# error: redefinition of 'sync' as different kind of symbol namespace

Tags: unit-testing, c++17, googletest

I am facing the following challenge when using googletest. I have embedded googletest with

```
add_subdirectory(src/googletest)
```

in my cmake and it compiled and executed fine.

All by test usually run fine except when i try to test one particular module with specific namespace with the word sync  in that namespace i.e.

```
using namespace sync::thbz;
```

I use google test to test the code but i have noticed when i want to test that particular module with the namespace sync it does not work i.e. i get

```
/src/sync.thbz.cpp/src/test/RandomTestString.cpp:26:17: error: expected namespace name
using namespace sync::thbz;
                ^
/usr/include/unistd.h:973:13: note: 'sync' declared here
extern void sync (void) __THROW;
        ^
```

and another similar error:

```
In file included from /src/sync.thbz.cpp/src/test/RandomTestString.cpp:20:
/srcn/sync.thbz.cpp/src/shared/ByteBuffer.h:48:11: error: redefinition of 'sync' as different kind of symbol
namespace sync::thbz {
          ^
/usr/include/unistd.h:973:13: note: previous definition is here
extern void sync (void) __THROW;
            ^
In file included from /src/sync.thbz.cpp/src/test/RandomTestString.cpp:21:
```

when i go and take a look into the header file of **/usr/include/unistd.h** i see in the line 973 the following code

```
/* Make all changes done to all files actually appear on disk.  */
extern void sync (void) __THROW;
```

is there any workaround for such problem since I really do not want to change the namespace just because i decided to use the googletest for that purpouse. What i doing something wrong here? If I disable this module that has the namespace sync in it test all other test are running fine. Is there any workaround that does not force me to change the namespace here ?

Answer (score 1):

C++ has namespaces precisely because of this sort of issue, but C doesn’t.  You don’t really have an option other than to avoid the “famous” names from **every** C library (including POSIX) with which your code *might* be used—now or in the future!—just like you have to avoid every other top-level C++ namespace.  (It’s technically an ODR violation even if the conflicting declarations never appear (typically via `#include`) in the same translation unit, although it’s hard to imagine anything really breaking then.)

Conveniently, some libraries (including the Windows API) use a different `NamingConvention`, so their symbols never collide with `those_from` POSIX and the C++ standard library (which of course include all lowercase words).

Comment: Davis many thanks for the reply, i was suspecting that i would really need to change the namespace but i was hoping for a miracle :)